# Privacy Policy in Play Console

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a project which worked well but now Google Play removed it, I don't now problem what is can you help me for solving the problem[image]

Comment: It looks like the app is uploading user image information without disclosing that it’s doing so in the privacy policy in Play Console. Seems like the fix would be to disclose that.

Comment: how  disclose that in play console

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?hl=en, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311#safetysection, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311?visit_id=637570411965975172-4240498562&rd=1, etc